# How do i parse Google's suggestqueries JSON response?

Tags: javascript, json

Before the following URL gave a JSON output:
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&q=Query

now it outputs the following:

```
window.google.ac.h(["Query",[["query",0],["query optimization",0],["query in access 2013",0],["query processing and optimization",0],["query optimization in dbms",0],["querying microsoft sql server 2012",0],["query in access 2010",0],["query letter",0],["querying microsoft sql server 2012 tutorial",0],["query access",0]],{"k":1,"q":"4-l7QUSZEiiQKaSq-yXfrtfHpd0"}])
```

Curious as to how i can parse this into JSON

Answer (score 3):

That's JSONP.

If you were to call this using JSONP technique (adding `<script>` tag to your page with the `src=` attribute set to the URL) then you would need to declare the function `window.google.ac.h` before making the JSONP call to process the result.

If you were to call this using ajax or on the server then you have two options:

1. declare the funciton `window.google.ac.h` to process the result then eval the response. (Because, that's what adding a `<script>` tag does, it evals the javascript file in your page. So you're basically just emulating JSONP)

   ```
   function window.google.ac.h (json) {
       // process your response here
   }
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.src = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?' +
           'client=youtube&ds=yt&q=Query';
   document.body.appendChild(s);
   ```

   alternatively, if you receive the response via other means:

   ```
   function window.google.ac.h (json) {
       // process your response here
   }
   eval(response);
   ```
2. Remove the outer `window.google.ac.h(` .. and .. `)` from the response then parse it as JSON.

   ```
   var json = response.replace(/^.*?\(/,'').replace(/\)$/,'');
   ```

Comment: ahk gotcha :D sorry for asking such a newbie question but would be possible to give the code snippet as to how it would be in either or both of the above cases? never used JSONP before so a wee bit confused still